# Optimizing an SQL query with very large amounts of data

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

First things first: I've looked for similar questions but found nothing that explains why what I'm doing is bad practice so I'm posting a new question even though this is very basic stuff.

I've received complaints that I'm putting too much stress on our db but I can't figure out how to optimize so I'm looking for help here.

I've attached a picture of the structure I'm dealing with at the bottom. What I'm trying to do is the following:
I need to get a list of people that have performed a specific userAction (lets say 'viewProduct' and then add information about that person regarding their userAge, country and continent.

Ive written the following:

```
select  u.userId, u.userAge, c.countryName, co.name, ul.createdTime,
        ul.userAction
    from  user_log as ul
    left join  user as u  ON u.userId = ul.userId
    left join  country as c  ON c.id = u.userCountryId
    left join  continent as co  ON co.id = c.continentId
    where  ul.createdTime > '2016-06-01'
      and  u.userAge > 40
      and  (ul.userAction like 'viewProduct'
              or  ul.userAction like 'storeProduct'
              or  ul.userAction like 'addProduct'
           );
```

And this is apparently not good enough so I sincerely hope that someone might be able to help out on how to make this more efficient. I'm not very used to dealing with tables where the entries are in the hundreds of millions.

Thank you in advance!

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lwsf.png)

Comment: Are there indexes on the columns you use in `join`s and `where`?

Comment: Is user data exist in all four tables every time or it depends. Another thing you are using like in improper way use % sign before and after the text according to your search requirement.

Comment: for optimization a query plan would be helpful. One question is if there are any indexes on your ID's you are joining on

Comment: Having `u.userAge > 40` in the `WHERE` clause makes the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `user` an `INNER JOIN`. That said, I'm guessing your data is structured in such a way that you probably want to use `INNER JOINS` everywhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple issues in the query:

1. In case you do not have limits and no indexes - MySQL will check all 100000000 records from user_log to give the result. To decrease amount of processed records, add index to "ul.createdTime" and also to "ul.userAction". This even can by a composed index (createdTime, userAction).
2. "ul.userAction like 'viewProduct'" is equal to "ul.userAction = 'viewProduct'". And whole construction can be refactored to "ul.userAction in ('viewProduct', 'storeProduct', 'addProduct')"
3. Move "u.userAge > 40" into join condition. And also index on "u.userAge" would help a lot.
4. I'm not sure, it depends on you data, but sometimes "inner join user as u" may work faster then "left join user as u". So, you could play here. (However logic of query will be changed)

Adding indexes to a table with 100000000 records is a long task. So, for testing purpose I would make a copy of "user_log" with last 1000000 records only and measure performance on it. Then I would add all mentioned indexes and test this query:

```
select u.userId, u.userAge, c.countryName, co.name, ul.createdTime,     ul.userAction 
from user_log as ul
left join user as u
    on u.userId = ul.userId and u.userAge > 40
left join country as c
    on c.id = u.userCountryId
left join continent as co
on co.id = c.continentId
where ul.createdTime > '2016-06-01' and 
ul.userAction in('viewProduct', 'storeProduct', 'addProduct');
```

.. and compare performance.

Please, let us know, does it help you?

Comment: Flip it around -- `(userAction, createdTime)`.  Index usage stops at the first "range" (`createdTime > ...`)

Comment: Again, start with the `=`, then the range:  `(userId, userAge)`